# i want to retrieve shipping address with amazon pay express method

Tags: amazon-pay

I want to make a php code to retreive shipping addres. I found docs here[https://pay.amazon.com/us/developer/documentation/express/201797700] and

they tell us to call this http post request..bellow, can you help me to make php code to post that request, please..  make a code to run php or jquery, how I can run this to return result..

```
POST /OffAmazonPayments/2013-01-01 HTTP/1.1 
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded 
Host: mws.amazonservices.com 
User-Agent:  

AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJKYFSJU7PEXAMPLE 
&Action=GetOrderReferenceDetails
&AccessToken=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN    
&AmazonOrderReferenceId=P01-1234-56

&MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.4ea38b7b-f563-7709-4bae-87aeaEXAMPLE &SellerId='YOUR_SELLER_ID_HERE'
&SignatureMethod = 'HmacSHA256'    
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp='2012-11-05'
&Version=2013-01-01 

&Signature=CLZOdtJGjAo81IxaLoE7af6HqK0EXAMPLE
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO :)

I suggest to have a look at the example [on github](https://github.com/amzn/amazonpay-express-demo/tree/master/php) 
To receive the shipping address you have to set the shippingAddressRequired-flag (data-ap-shipping-address-required) to "yes" like it is mentioned [here](https://pay.amazon.com/us/developer/documentation/express/201737770)

Afterwards you can to a GetOrderReferenceDetails-Api-call find the documentation [here](https://pay.amazon.com/us/developer/documentation/apireference/201751970). Id use the [php-sdk](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php) from github for that call. The request is defnied in the [client class](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php/blob/master/AmazonPay/Client.php#L553)